# To use Dictionary<string, int> get a list of tags in orchard

Tags: c#, razor, orchardcms

I  use a `Dictionary<string, int>`, to get a list of tags in Orchard.

There are 2 errors:

> 1. @foreach (var pair in tagsDictionary.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Value.Count()))----CS1061 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
> 2. @pair.Value.Count-----CS0119 “ValueExtensions.Value(HtmlHelper, string)”is a method, which is not valid in the given context.

Please  help!

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement
@using Orchard.Tags.Models
@{
    var items = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)Model.ContentItems);

    var tagsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();


    // Collect categories and their items.
    foreach (var item in items) {

        var tagNames = item.As<TagsPart>().CurrentTags;
        var pairs = tagNames;

        foreach (var pair in pairs) {
            var list = tagsDictionary.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? tagsDictionary[pair.Value.Count] : default(int);

            if (list == null) {
                list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                tagsDictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.Count);
            }

            list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
<ul>
    @foreach (var pair in tagsDictionary.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.Value.Count()))
    {
        var pairItems = tagsDictionary.ToList();
        <li>
           @pair.Key
            <span>@pair.Value.Count</span>
          
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Please learn some C#/Razor and use a IDE like Visual Studio. This is your 3rd question about basic C# programming, not specific for Orchard. An `int` type doesn't have a method `Count`, because it already is an `integer`. So you can just remove the `.Count()`. Also below that, just remove `.Count` of your `@pair.Value.Count`

Comment: devqon,  Thanks, I'm leaning c# .Your help makes me less detours